# Properly constrain the number of specific records in SQL and Hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails-orm

In my scenario a `PLAYER` can perform 2 `ACTIONS` per day (for example, can attack 2 other players per day). I implemented two persistent classes: `Player` and `Action`. `Action` class has references to `Player` and `Date` of this very action (date contains only date part, say 2013-01-15 00:00:00). I want to create a database-level constraint which limits number of `Action` records with the specific date to 2. This will prevent players to perform more than 2 actions per day. The system is highly concurrent and application-level checks usually fail, allowing players perform 3-4 actions simultaneously.

My current solution is to implement a third versioned entity `PlayerDayActions` with references to `player`, `date`, `action1` and `action2`. Thus I can check whether `action1 IS NULL` or `action2 IS NULL` to count how many actions a player has already performed, and the version on `PlayerDayAction` will disallow to overwrite the concurrently modified instance, if there would be any. To scale, I can change action1 and action2 to a list and check such a list.

Is there a more clean and scalable solution for the problem? In plain SQL in Hibernate? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you create the third table PlayerDayAction, have the columns Player, date, action.  Add a record per action, and IF (PLAYER HAS EQUAL TO 2 ACTIONS TODAY) don't allow the action.  Unless you want the data for historical purposes, you could even delete the data every night or weekly so the table doesn't get too large.

That's how I'd do it :).

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the system is highly concurrent, and user can send requests to perform multiple actions simultaneously (e.g. via script) and my system will process such requests in parallel threads. Therefore, if the player has already performed a single action, and requests to perform 2 another (in parallel requests) both of the processing threads will see that there was only 1 action from this user today, and allow him to perform 2 another (instead of one). So, this will end with 3 PlayerDayAction records instead of two. This is why I need a database-level check